# Find out if IIS is installed by examining the Registry

Tags: windows, windows-7, registry, windows-server-2008, inno-setup

I have an innosetup installer that needs to create an IIS Virtual Directory. In order to create the virtual directory, IIS Management Service must be enabled.

[image: Windows Features]

How do I check which Windows Features are enabled? The best solution would be to check a registry setting, but other methods that are possible via innosetup are fine.

The solution should work with XP, Vista, Win7, Win2003 server and Win2008 server (32 and 64 bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know offhand how to generically tell which features are installed.
In the specific case of IIS, you can tell by looking for this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp
```

IIS is installed if that key exists.  If the key is missing, IIS is not installed.

[More details here.](http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2007/03/01/107732.aspx)