# How to detect if IIS is Installed and ASP/ASP.NET is Registered in a windows system using c++?

Tags: c++, iis

I am using windows 7.

How to detect if IIS is Installed and ASP/ASP.NET is Registered in a windows system using c++?

Can I achieve this using ahadmin apis in C++?

Or If I read any registrykeys whether I will come to know about this?

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out if IIS is installed by examining the Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601605/find-out-if-iis-is-installed-by-examining-the-registry)

Answer (score 0):

You could get to know whether IIS is installed by checking the registry key **Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp.**

To detect whether asp.net asp has been installed,you could check the registry **keyComputer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Components**

If you wonder whether asp.net has been registered, you could check the registry key **Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\2.0.x** and **Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\4.0.x**